# Binding fileupload control to managed bean

Tags: dojo, xpages, managed-bean

I´m binding a fileupload control to a managed bean. The property within the managed bean is of type "UploadedFile". When I save the Bean I get the following client side javascript error:

> dojo/parser::parse() error SyntaxError: Unexpected token )(…)

This occurs only with managed beans. When the control is bound to a domino document there is no such error.

Here is some code for you: I use the very basic version of the control and instantly get the javascript error:

```
<xp:fileUpload id="fileUpload1" 
    value="#{registration.User.attachment}">
</xp:fileUpload>
```

Does anyone have experience with this or is there any property which I forgot to set?

Comment: Is the answer to this question also the solution for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073250/how-to-upload-and-save-an-attachment-via-xpages-java-bean?

Comment: Code rulez! Provide your code, so we can spot what doesn't work

Comment: Provided some code. Paul, I don´t think so, since I wonder about a Javascript Error which is thrown. I know how to bind it and everything and it does even work. But I get these ugly javascript error on every save.

Comment: Is it just me or is anyone able to reproduce this error?

Comment: (most of us here) know how a domino document datasource works, but there's no chance knowing anything about your bean. This could be anything...