# How to run LotusScript agent from Xpages without saving document

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, xpages-ssjs

is it possible to run a lotusscript agent from a Xpages form which is not saved yet? I have `"xspFrmTest.xsp"` page,  lotusscript agent name `(wsAgent)`

When i open `/xspFrmTest.xsp?action?newDocument`  then with a button i call Lotusscript agent but as far as i know I can not call agent without savind document? is it possible to call it from new Xpages document(Xpages form)

Just wondering its possibility. 

Regards
C.A.

**UPDATE**

```
Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem
Set rtitem = doc.GetFirstItem("Body")
If (rtitem.Type = RICHTEXT ) Then
ForAll o In rtitem.EmbeddedObjects
If ( o.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT ) Then
sFilePath = "E:\AttachFolder\" + o.Name
Call o.ExtractFile(sFilePath)
End If
End ForAll
End If
```

Comment: Try NotesAgent.RunWithDocumentContext(). You can find examples for XPage- use in Domino Designer help...

Comment: Thank you so much. The only question is, is it possible to work with attachments? 

I updated my question

Comment: this may also be usefull to get rid of LS part... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073250/how-to-upload-and-save-an-attachment-via-xpages-java-bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may not be able to use or reach any of attachments before until i save the document